# xml as data source for flex charts

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

Here is MXML  code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- charts/XMLFileDataProvider.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >
<mx:Model id="results" source="data.xml"/>
<mx:Panel title="Line Chart">
 <mx:LineChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{results.result}" showDataTips="true" width="600" height="240">
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
       <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="month"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:series>
       <mx:LineSeries yField="banana" displayName="Banana"/>
       <mx:LineSeries yField="apple" displayName="Apple"/>
       <mx:LineSeries yField="orange" displayName="Orange"/>
    </mx:series>
 </mx:LineChart>
 <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>     
 </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

When i change the data in xml file the changes are not reflected in the chart.Can anyone tell me where i my going wrong

here is xml file

```
      <data>
<result month="Jan-04">
    <apple>81768</apple>
    <orange>60310</orange>
    <banana>43357</banana>
</result>
<result month="Feb-04">
    <apple>81156</apple>
    <orange>58883</orange>
    <banana>49280</banana>

   </data>
```

Comment: It will not refresh because you are getting data only at initial loading for Chart application. If you want to make it load every change of data (i.e. XML) you have to call/get data every time from XML. To do this you can create one timer in your application, which will load this data again and again after some interval. You can create one attribute in XML which will show change of XML (like random number) Create one variable and catch in it. Check if that catch number is same as previous one if not assign XML data to Chart dataProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you, i have created example with respect to HTTPService: -

You can implement logic as per above comment for you question.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="init();switchImage()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <!--<fx:Model id="results" />-->
        <s:HTTPService id="results" result="resultHandler(event)" fault="{trace('Fault')}" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            private function init():void
            {
                var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, switchImage);
                timer.start();
            }
            private function switchImage(event:TimerEvent = null):void
            {
                //url as external URL outside of project folder
                results.url = "C:/data/data.xml";
                results.send();
            }

            private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                myChart.dataProvider = null;
                myChart.dataProvider = event.result.data.result;
            } 
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Panel title="Line Chart">
        <mx:LineChart id="myChart" showDataTips="true" width="600" height="240">
            <mx:horizontalAxis>
                <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="month"/>
            </mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:series>
                <mx:LineSeries yField="banana" displayName="Banana"/>
                <mx:LineSeries yField="apple" displayName="Apple"/>
                <mx:LineSeries yField="orange" displayName="Orange"/>
            </mx:series>
        </mx:LineChart>
        <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>     
    </mx:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: in  results.url i placed the location of xml file but still i am not able to see the plot

Comment: Keep your XML "out side of your project" For example on Desktop than try. It will work

Comment: I placed in C:data/data.xml and  results.url="C:/data/data.xml" but still not able to see anything on graph

Comment: i am able to execute by placing results.url = "C:/data/data.xml"; i have edited some code. Now you can check.

Comment: in line chart id dont you think  need to specify the data source

Comment: Yes you can do that by using binding concept.